# How can i use the tinymce editor at admin area of asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I'm trying using tinymce editor at my asp.net mvc project.
I installed on mvc project with following nuget package.it's okay with that in front-side.But this is not okay in back-end (admin area)

http://www.nuget.org/packages/TinyMCE.MVC.Sample/

How can i implement to asp.net mvc areas ?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. What do you mean by admin area?

Comment: I'm meaning asp.net mvc areas.See at the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx) , For example how can i use it at areas that i created ?

Comment: that package is way too old :) It is probably out of sync with latest TinyMCE versions, too. I'd take a look at latest TinyMCE documentation and implement it from scratch. It has been too long since I had a look at TinyMCE. So, I'm not much of help here :s